# Why would a Twitter widget only work locally?

Tags: twitter

Works locally but not here...

http://staging.bangface.com/TwitterTest.aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser's JavaScript error console.

> You have not whitelisted this domain for your Twitter widget. Go to https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/274159032581885952/edit and add 'staging.bangface.com' to the 'Domains' list for this timeline.

Comment: Aha! Working with 'localhost' threw me way off.